# Extracting Rich text contents to HTML file

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotusscript

I am trying to extract rich text content in document to HTML File.

Searched for code in this forum. Found below code.

Code is extracting contents into HTML file, with "Anonymous" access at the database level.

But after removing "Anonymous" from ACL and tried to pass username and password along with the request. But it is extracting authentication page ( not the rich text content in document). ( Server is SSO disabled).

Any ideas how to do the authentication on "get" request?

Thanks in Advance..

```vb
Function GetHtmlFromField(docunid As string, fieldname As String) As String
    Dim obj

    Set obj = CreateObject("msxml2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0")

    obj.open "GET", "Url" + docunid + "/" + fieldname + "?openfield&charset=utf-8", False,"username", "password"
    //obj.SetRequestHeader "encoding", "utf-8"
    //obj.setTimeouts 5000, 5000, 10000, 10000
    obj.SetRequestHeader "Authorization", "Basic MY_AUTH_STRING"
    obj.send("")

    Dim html As String
    html = Trim$(obj.responseText)

    GetHtmlFromField = html
    End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following format for the URL:

```
username:password@http://server/mydb.nsf/docunid [...]
```

BTW you should check

```
obj.open "GET", "Url" + docunid
```

Url should be a variable I think.

Comment: Thanks for your inputs.I tried to pass URL as Http://username:pwd@url , but it is returning as "invalid" URL

Comment: See my corrected answer, sorry for the error. You also look at http://www.dagerot.com/2008/02/13/login-in-with-just-url-arguments/

Comment: Thanks alot..it worked perfeclty..http://domain.com/names.nsf?login&username=name&password=pass&redirectto=/database.nsf/view/key

Comment: Fine, my pleasure, don't forget to vote if it solved your problem.